# How to set some seconds if element has dynamic class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

is it possible to check if a class already exists for a amount of time. So p.e.

```
if ($('#element').hasClass('acitve').exisits-until('500ms')) {
do something
}
else {
}
```

THX

Comment: Don't you know when the class got added?   If not, why not?

Comment: The class 'active' was changing on scroll from one to other elements. So if you scroll fast it changes fast through this elements. If stop scrolling the active class will rest on one element in condition where scrolling stopped or is very slow. I want to only do something if the active class stays on an element for a while.

Comment: Right, so the thing to do is put an extra listener on that scroll event, or hook into the place where that class is being added.    Set a timer, for example, and cancel it if the scroll stops that element from having the class.   Actually watching the element is almost guaranteed to be the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to catch when class changed then add your function .

I made a simple example to toggle between two classes then make function when specific class is active , I used `setInterval` function .

```js
var test = setInterval(change, 500);

function change() {

  $(".change , .active").toggleClass("change active");

  if ($('#element').hasClass('active')) {

    var add = $('#result').val();

    $('#result').val((parseInt(add) + 1));

  }

}
```

```css
.active {
  background: red
}

.change {
  background: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text class=change id=element>
<input type=text value=1 id=result>
```

Comment: When using the code snippet tool there's a link which says "Tidy", please use it, it makes your code a lot more readable.

Comment: Thanks , I just know that , I'll do

Comment: Mohammed and Darren, thank you for showing the way. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Exact requirement is not clear , try `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(function(){
  if ($('#element').hasClass('acitve')) {
     do something
  }
else {}
},500)
```

Comment: If requirements are not clear, ask for them to be expanded on with a comment.

Comment: Hi, thank you brk and Alnitak. Question: So this code does mean, if the class 'active' exists for at least 500ms or longer do something after else? This is not realy clear to me.